# Wrong $language_content variable

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using entity translation module for node localization and `dpm($language_content)` always gives english, which is my default language. This outcome is for all languages, I don't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$language_content` variable is not set to the language used for the currently shown node, but it contains the value set by the language negotiation providers.

See [`language_initialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21language.inc/function/language_initialize/7), which is the function that initialize that and other variables, and that is called from the following code.

```
  // Ensure the language is correctly returned, even without multilanguage
  // support. Also make sure we have a $language fallback, in case a language
  // negotiation callback needs to do a full bootstrap.
  // Useful for eg. XML/HTML 'lang' attributes.
  $default = language_default();
  foreach ($types as $type) {
    $GLOBALS[$type] = $default;
  }
  if (drupal_multilingual()) {
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/language.inc';
    foreach ($types as $type) {
      $GLOBALS[$type] = language_initialize($type);
    }
    // Allow modules to react on language system initialization in multilingual
    // environments.
    bootstrap_invoke_all('language_init');
  }
```

The language negotiation providers are the ones you set in admin/config/regional/language/configure.

> [image: screenshot]

If none of the provider is enabled, which what happens by default, that variable will be set with an object for English language.

Comment: Thanks. The Url row of Content language detection of disabled.

Comment: Its strange that all was working correctly(nodes, menu translations) inspite of metatag module.